# Start HTML5 video at a particular position when loading?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I need HTML5 video to start at certain point.  Let's say at time 50 seconds onward.

I tried but its not working as expected. is there something i am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
   <video id="vid1" width="640" height="360">
       <source src="file.webm" type="video/webm" /> 
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
   <script>
       document.getElementById('vid1').currentTime = 50;
   </script>
```

When the page loads, it just starts playing from beginning. 
However if I call this during playback like after some time, it works fine. 
Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: What browsers? Have you tried delaying the call a few miliseconds? Maybe it's taking a little longer to fully load the video element

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You have to wait until the browser knows the duration of the video before you can seek to a particular time. So, I think you want to wait for the 'loadedmetadata' event something like this:

```
document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 50;
}, false);
```

Comment: This does not work in Safari. I tried loadeddata event too. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. This is an issue with WEBM format. MP4 works fine.

Comment: Use 'durationchange' event and always call pause before making changes to playing video

Answer (score 97):

WITHOUT USING JAVASCRIPT

Just add `#t=[(start_time), (end_time)]` to the end of your media URL. The only setback (if you want to see it that way) is you'll need to know how long your video is to indicate the end time.
**Example:**

```
<video>
    <source src="splash.mp4#t=10,20" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**Notes:** Not supported in IE

Comment: the second digit doesn't seem to end how much of the video was loaded to begin with... first digit worked tho. Any thoughts?

Comment: this doesn't really work well. the browser still preload as much as it wants, maybe just start and end at where you decided, but the preload didn't stop...

Comment: if you don't want to specify the end time you can simply do add `#t=10`

Comment: This is easily the simplest and best solution for starting video at a certain time

Comment: If you use `autoplay` and `muted` attributes none of the other uses are useful with js, but this one works properly.

Comment: Just to add, this is called media fragments, see more in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/

Comment: also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery#specifying_playback_range

Answer (score 63):

You can link directly with [Media Fragments URI](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/), just change the filename to *file.webm#t=50*

[Here's an example](http://www.annodex.net/~silvia/itext/mediafrag.html#t=40)

This is pretty cool, you can do all sorts of things. But I don't know the current state of browser support.

Comment: Browser support is good. I think all HTML5 supporting browsers also support at least the basic temporal media fragments.

Comment: @michaelhanon, it would be rather easy to write a polyfill for IE to achieve that. Detect browser, if not supported, break up URL, find the query parameter, use Javascript to change the video's time... I might do it if I get a chance

Comment: is there a fragment to set the END time?

Comment: It even allows fractions of a second after a dot: `#t=17.79` ^_^

Answer (score 36):

adjust video start and end time when using the video tag in html5;

http://www.yoursite.com/yourfolder/yourfile.mp4#t=5,15

where left of comma is start time in seconds, right of comma is end time in seconds. 
drop the comma and end time to effect the start time only.

Comment: the second digit doesn't seem to end how much of the video was loaded to begin with... first digit worked tho. Any thoughts?

Comment: When working with browsers, it's always better to check the W3C spec and caniuse.com to see how widely supported a feature is. (The best StackOverflow answers link to the specs.) In this case, they're called 'Media Fragments', and the spec is here. https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/

Answer (score 6):

On Safari Mac for an HLS source, I needed to use the loadeddata event instead of the metadata event.

Comment: I think the loadedmetadata is supposed to be the correct event, but I too was getting seekable.length 0 (only in Safari on OSX) unless I listened for dataloaded. Thanks

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's probably not directly related to the example provided by the OP, but it's factually accurate and relevant to the general subject of the question.