# "Start time" on TED video embeds

Tags: html, video, embed, jwplayer

http://jsfiddle.net/N8dYL/

The goal i'm trying to acchieve is that when you click play, the TED Talk starts playing at for example 02:22

I've tried several things i know from JWplayer like `video.mp4?time=02:22` but I couldn't get it to work on this player.

Does anyone have some inspiration for me?

Comment: If you want to time stamp on a URL you can use the transcript feature to get a url, which will start at a given point. Example: http://www.ted.com/talks/deborah_gordon_digs_ants#t-459000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing i can think of is downloading the mp4, and using JWplayer, like i just did.

Comment: Yes - most likely this is just not possible with the TEDPlayer.

Answer (score 7):

***AAhHH! I just noticed that when I pause a TED Talk, the url at the top changes with that number! So it's far easier that what I posted below - just pause the talk where you want and copy the URL!***

Seems that when you use certain social media plugins/extensions (I'm using MeetEdgar on Chrome), you can click to share from the bookmark button when you pause the TED video and it will give a unique time number. I just did this one: http://www.ted.com/talks/julian_treasure_how_to_speak_so_that_people_want_to_listen#t-28636

There is no clear pattern, though, as the #t-xxxxx for 10 seconds was 426018, 20 seconds was 8651, 30 seconds 18670 and the one above was at 40 seconds.

I'm guessing the player creates a random number for that specific point. Probably so that people don't share just bits, but the whole thing.

I'm only guessing that some of the Twitter, Facebook or G+ plugins/extensions might do the same. Give it a shot!

~Bon

Comment: It works well but does not work when I embed the video, any clue?

Comment: Thank you so much. I will put "#t-500" to every TED video to skip that staring sound.

Answer (score 2):

this post may help

[Start HTML5 video at a particular position when loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981427/start-html5-video-at-a-particular-position-when-loading)

or at least that's what i hope lol :D

make sure you read this

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/

you might find it helpful after all :D

Comment: I already solved it by hosting it on my own CDN and using jwplayer, their CDN didn't support it neither did their player. To bad you are just easy bounty hunter.

Comment: I'm not a bounty hunter, i have answered the question because i have a video hosting site and i want to add something like that on my site lol so i was doing a research for me and you...and I don't care about my reputation here lol, i want to have about 75 only coz then i can vote up and down and comment on the question...more reputation won't do me any good, I'm not so active here. I'm a top contributor on yahooanswers.com programming section and only come to here if the  question will not be answered there..i ask on 6 forums including this one...never cared stupid about points