# Start playing video from a specific location using html5 video tag

Tags: javascript, html, video

Is it possible to start playing a video from a specific location (for instance the second minute of the video clip) using html5 video tag? If it is how can it be done? Can it be done using JavaScript?

Comment: Duplicate: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5983220/720771)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start HTML5 video at a particular position when loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981427/start-html5-video-at-a-particular-position-when-loading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible. You can use `player.currentTime` attribute. see here for an example  http://singintime.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/html5-video-seeking-with-javascript/