# How to create links to seek within videojs

Tags: html5-video

I am not a coder but I am able to successfully create the function I want with JWPlayer:

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
   file: "media/video.mp4",
    image: "images/title.gif",
     controls: true,
      width: 320,
  height: 240
  });
 </script>
```

With the above script, the following link will seek to 1 minute: a href="#" onclick="jwplayer(myElement).seek(60)"

---

How can I create similar html links for videojs to be able to seek to arbitrary points in the video?

Comment: have you tried anything ideojs has an api which would allow you to do the same thing very similarly here's the link https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/api.md

Comment: I am not a coder. I can work from examples. Pointing me to the list of APIs does not help. Thanks.

Comment: that's not how it works! if you wanna do it by yourself, you have to learn. (otherwise you can pay me ;-) ) here is how you seek: http://blog.grio.com/2012/08/how-to-seek-an-html5-video-at-a-specific-time-on-load.html

Comment: and here especially for video js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663962/is-there-a-way-to-seek-to-a-certain-time-in-a-video-using-javascript