# Enable a button after playing 70% of video

Tags: php, html, flash, video

I have one order page where I added one video using following code,

```
    <object id=0 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/player_flv_maxi.swf" width=445 height=300>
        <param name="movie" value=<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/player_flv_maxi.swf />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="menu" value="true" />
        <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
        <param name="autoload" value="true" />
        <param name="FlashVars" value="flv=<?=$video?>&autoplay=1&autoload=1&buffer=5&buffermessage=&playercolor=464646&loadingcolor=999898&buttoncolor=ffffff&buttonovercolor=dddcdc&slidercolor=ffffff&sliderovercolor=dddcdc&showvolume=1&showfullscreen=1&playeralpha=100&title=My Action Wealth&margin=0&buffershowbg=0" />
      </object>
```

And I have one order now button below the video, which is initially disabled, I want to enable this button only after playing a 70-80% of video.

I don't have any idea how to do this I searched on Google also on stack overflow but didn't found the ans.

Anyone please help..

Comment: there'is no way to do that except that flash object can send a request to server on the event you described

Comment: Can you able to tell me how to do that or any tutorial or site where I can get more info about it ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know ActionScript. Anyway I guess you don't have source code for that flash video player. If I'm right then the only way to solve the task is to use HTML5 Video and try to use JavaScript properties like there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981427/start-html5-video-at-a-particular-position-when-loading