# Start a video at a particular time and keep track of the video

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, html5-video, azure-media-player

This is a 2 part question.

I am playing a video using `Azure Media Player`. The code is given below. I am just displaying the `URL` of the video and it starts to play.

1. I need to know how to play the video at a particular time (Let's say at 0.19 Sec)
2. How can I keep track of the time the video has being playing

   ```
   <video oncontextmenu="return false;"  id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" autoplay width="640" height="400"  data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
       <source src={{url}} >
   </video>
   ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981427/start-html5-video-at-a-particular-position-when-loading

Comment: @boxdox Can this be used with Typescript/angular. Sorry I am new to this

Comment: that is a browser property, so it should work. try it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [AMP docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/azure-media-player/azure-media-player-api-methods) and the [API docs](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html) for more info.

```js
var myPlayer = amp("vid1", function(){
    //this is the ready function and will only execute after the player is loaded

    myPlayer.currentTime(19);  // immediately after the video is ready, this will set the time to 19 seconds
});

// in this case, assume `startCounter` and `stopCounter` are functions
// you created that start and pause a timer to keep track of how long someone
// has actually been playing the content.
myPlayer.addEventListener(amp.eventName.play, startCounter);
myPlayer.addEventListener(amp.eventName.pause, pauseCounter);

// or use `timeupdate` if you would rather just keep track of the current
// playback position.
myPlayer.addEventListener(amp.eventName.timeupdate, someFunc);
```